# VB Win Form Issue Using SqlCommand

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, sqlcommand

I am currently creating a win form based tool in Visual Studio 2019 that reads data from a SQL database. I am having difficulty when pulling a field from the form I am working in into the sqlCommand query.

This is part of my VB script. Note that this works fine without the Surname like filter, it also works if i write it with a hard-coded surname, such as 'Adams'. I can also get the same logic to work using variables directly in SQL. The message pop-up displays 'Adams' as expected but nothing is returned in the data-grid.

Screen-shots below of the result of running the form as desired and when hard-coded to 'Adams'.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

```
Public Class Form4
Public Sub BtnFetchAdastraUser_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFetchAdastraUser.Click

    Dim connetionString As String = "Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx"
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(
                                        "select 
                                            [u].[UserRef],
                                            [u].[UserName],
                                            [u].[FullName]
                                        from dbo.[Users][u]
                                        where
                                            [Obsolete] = 0
                                                and [Surname] like '%" + Surname.Text + "%'", connection
                                      )
        command.Connection.Open()
        Dim sqlAdaptr As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim ds As New DataTable
        sqlAdaptr.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

        MsgBox(Surname.Text)

        command.Connection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I ran command.CommandText through my MsgBox and it highlighted the below issue with what I was passing through in the query!

I'd added text to the front of the field I was passing through.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use parameters to write SQL query statements.
It can be changed as follows:

```
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(
                                        "select 
                                        [u].[UserRef],
                                        [u].[UserName],
                                        [u].[FullName]
                                    from dbo.[Users][u]
                                    where
                                        [Obsolete] = 0
                                            and [Surname] like @Surname", connection
                                      )
        command.Parameters.Clear()
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", "%" & Surname.Text & "%")

        Dim sqlAdaptr As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim ds As New DataTable
        sqlAdaptr.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

        MsgBox(Surname.Text)
        MsgBox(command.CommandText)

        command.Connection.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: Using parameters: not just recommended but **mandatory** practice. All it takes to crash this code is a surname like O'connor. Besides, the input from a textbox should be sanitized, use the trim function to eliminate possible whitespace. When doing copy-paste, extra spaces, tabs, carriage returns sneak in frequently.

Comment: Yes, here, `Surname.Text` can be anything and it could break the query if it has ' in it.